# Using single lane superspeed(usb 3)part with usb c port

Tags: usb

I need to use usb c connector for usb 3.0 chips(slave) only supports single superspeed lane. master can be single (usb a type, using a to c cable) or dual superspeed lane(usb c type). How can i implement it?
Some ideas:

connect only one lanes, and another one is floating:it will not work if i connect it reverse when master is single lane.

Using superspeed mux:additional mcu is required because i need to detect signal flow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you plan to work outside the USB standard and just reuse USB connectors and cables?